# How to check presence of attribute in module using pylint

Tags: python, pylint

I use pylint(verstion 1.6.4) for static analysis python code to follow PEP8, and I need to verify that my own required attributes are present in the current module.

Earlier it could be done by using 'required-attributes' variable in pylintrc file, but now it is obsolete.

Can anyone help me how to do this verification? Any other ways to achieve it?